# Find who created table constraint in azure sql database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a azure sql database. Is it possible to find out who created the constraint on table? Or at least when it was added? If yes, how can I do that? Is there any scripts/tools for that purposes?

thanks in advance

Comment: no it isn't possible to do that.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer or vote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL has a feature named AUDITING. If enabled either on the server and/or database you can define a storage account to send the "Server Audit" and "Database Audit" logs to. In Azure storage, auditing logs are saved as a collection of blob files within a container named sqldbauditlogs. Use Power BI for example you can view audit log data.

If this features is not enabled your will struggle I think to find your user unless the database is accessed using Azure AD identities.

Please note Advanced Threat Detection will alert you on unusual access patterns. Least privilege approach to access is recommend.

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing

Answer (score 0):

If you enable [Azure SQL Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing) you can try the following using PowerShell.

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing `
 -State Enabled `
 -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" `
 -ServerName "ssqlinstancename" `  #ssqlinstancename.database.windows.net
 -StorageAccountName "strageaccountname" `
 -DatabaseName "dbname" `
 -AuditActionGroup 'SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP' `
 -RetentionInDays 8 `
 -AuditAction "CREATE ON schema::dbo BY [public]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use below query to find out when the constraint created from all the SQL execution records.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 

QS.creation_time, 

SUBSTRING(ST.text,(QS.statement_start_offset/2)+1, 

((CASE QS.statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text) 

ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1 

) AS statement_text, 

ST.text, 

QS.total_worker_time, 

QS.last_worker_time, 

QS.max_worker_time, 

QS.min_worker_time 

FROM 

sys.dm_exec_query_stats QS 

CROSS APPLY 

sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) ST 

WHERE ST.text LIKE '%constraint_name%'

ORDER BY 

QS.creation_time DESC
```

This query will take a few time.

Hope this helps.